# tkinter not found when launching project as .exe

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I'm currently attempting to take one of my projects and turn it into a .exe file with cxfreeze. Unfortunately I've run into a problem I just cant seem to figure out, I'm hoping maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

So here's the setup code.

---

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "testproject1",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("Structured map.py", base=base)])'''
```

---

This is my setup file that I use to start the whole process. Both this file and my project lies in the root venv folder which also contains the actual python installation and all modules I have ever used.

I use "python setup.py" to initialize the building of the new file. Everything goes through, no issues so far...

When the whole process is done I navigate to the "build" file which gets written to the venv folder and inside that folder lies the new .exe file.

Here's the confusing part.

When I launch it i get the following error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"C:\users\owner\desktop\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze\initscripts\console.py"
Line 37, in run exec(code, {**name**':'**main**})
File "Structured map.py" line 3, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'

Why is it not finding the tkinter module? I can run the "structured map" file just fine with tkinter imported and it will find it, I have also checked around for previous solutions and tried to manually enter in tkinter and import tkinter in the build_exe_options but to no avail, I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"]}` aren't you excluding it?

Comment: You will have to add exclusions for everything that comes up with that error. Sadly it will only show you one at a time. What I ended up doing is looking of the lines in command prompt after running the setup and then adding everything it listed I didn't want to my excludes. This dropped my file size from 400+ mb to 13mb.

Comment: I am just stupid. That was the issue, I had EXCLUDED the damn thing. Thanks for the help.